# Objects are not valid as a React child - firebase database, axios

Tags: reactjs, firebase, axios

I am working on a tutorial where I use firebase to create my backend stuff and then my front end using react. I get said error and I think it has to do with my line of code: `this.state.screams.map((scream) => <Scream scream={scream} />)`. I am not sure how to fix it. Any help on how to write this would be appreciated.

I wrote my code on jsfiddle. Thank you!

https://jsfiddle.net/cvizena/8r3vpkdz/3/

```
// Scream.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';
import Link from 'react-router-dom/Link';

// MUI Stuff
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import Typorgraphy from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const styles = {
  card: {
    display: 'flex',
    marginBottom: 20
  },
  image: {
    minWidth: 200
  },
  content: {
    padding: 25,
    objectFit: 'cover'
  }
};

class Scream extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      classes,
      scream: {
        body,
        createdAt,
        userImage,
        userHandle,
        screamId,
        likeCount,
        commentCount
      }
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <Card className={classes.card}>
        <CardMedia
          image={userImage}
          title="Profile image"
          className={classes.image}/>
        <CardContent class={classes.content}>
          <Typorgraphy variant="h5">{userHandle}</Typorgraphy>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">{createdAt}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body1">{body}</Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}


// home.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

import Scream from '../components/Scream';

class home extends Component {
  state = {
    screams: null
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get('/screams')
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        this.setState({
          screams: res.data
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
  render() {
    let recentScreamsMarkup = this.state.screams ? (
      this.state.screams.map((scream) => <Scream scream={scream} />)
    ) : (
      <p>Loading...</p>
    );
    return (
      <Grid container spacing={16}>
        <Grid item sm={8} xs={12}>
          {recentScreamsMarkup}
        </Grid>
        <Grid item sm={4} xs={12}>
          <p>Profile...</p>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: the fiddle is giving a different error, duplicate React declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The jsx code should be inside the return statement, try this code

```
  render() {
    return this.state.screams ? (
      <Grid container spacing={16}>
        <Grid item sm={8} xs={12}>
          {this.state.screams.map((scream) => <Scream scream={scream} />}
        </Grid>
        <Grid item sm={4} xs={12}>
          <p>Profile...</p>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    ) : (
      <p>Loading...</p>
    );
  }
```

or also you can put the recentScreamsMarkup assignment outside the render function

Comment: It's still the same error..Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_seconds, _nanoseconds}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. I think it has to do with class Scream extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      classes,
      scream: {
        body,
        createdAt,
        userImage,
        userHandle,
        screamId,
        likeCount,
        commentCount
      }
    } = this.props;

Comment: Can you put how a `scream` object looks like, please? Seems like one of this props `body`, `createdAt` or `userHandle` is an object

Comment: 2 constants. Since I am accessing firebase collection using axios the details of the collection scream are each descriptor (i.e. userHandle, body, etc). The code is: class Scream extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      classes,
      scream: {
        body,
        createdAt,
        userImage,
        userHandle,
        screamId,
        likeCount,
        commentCount
      }
    } = this.props;

Comment: I mean the object you get in the axios call `res.data` which then you save in the screams state

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening because you're using map on this.state.screams - assign this.state.screams to a variable and then call map on the variable.

```
 let screamsVariable = this.state.screams
    let recentScreamsMarkup = screamsVariable ? (
      screamsVariable.map((scream) => <Scream scream={scream} />)
    ) : (
      <p>Loading...</p>
    );
```

Comment: Thanks, Ross - I get the same issue. So frustrated!

Comment: No, it didn't. I get the same issue

Comment: Try changing the initial state of screams to an empty array

Answer (score 0):

Some kind soul just helped me and explained the problem to me:

"The value of createdAt is an object with the keys which the error message describes. You have to tell React how to render that. A simple way to unblock you would look like this:

new Date(createdAt._seconds * 1000).toString()"

Thanks for your help guys!